# Non-scoped apps cannot specify token scopes when using dropbox api/oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

Anyone know why all of a sudden a dropbox registered app that's been working fine for years would suddenly show

```
{"error": "invalid_scope", "error_description": "Non-scoped apps cannot specify token scopes"}
```

When attempting to use an oauth refresh token like so.

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.dropbox.com
Content-Length: 363
Expect: 100-continue

refresh_token=<VALIDTOKEN>&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<VALIDCLIENTID>&client_secret=<VALIDSECRET>&scope=account_info.write+account_info.read+files.metadata.write+files.metadata.read+files.content.write+files.content.read+sharing.write+sharing.read+file_requests.write+file_requests.read+contacts.write
```

I'm guessing I need to do something to the registration of the app. That some new requirement is needed, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Long-time-registered-app-not-allowing-Oauth-authentication/td-p/667990 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received reply from Dropbox forum as below. Certainly sounds like my issue. Investigating

---

From your description, it sounds like you have a legacy non-scoped app from before we switched to registering new apps as scoped apps.

We recently fixed a bug where the API would allow non-scoped apps to specify scopes using the 'scope' parameter when calling /oauth2/token with 'grant_type=refresh_token'. Scopes don't apply to non-scoped apps so this is supposed to be rejected with the error you're seeing.

To correct this, you should either:

not provide the 'scope' parameter when calling /oauth2/token for the non-scoped app, or

migrate your non-scoped app to use scopes, which you can do using the "Permissions" tab of the app's page on the App Console.

Option b would be preferred. You can find more information on the migration here.

https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens

Comment: This was indeed exactly the issue.